# Yii2 save in the table user_id account

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-user

I'm a beginner in yii2 , I would like to save in the table associated with the account , the account id . Any suggestions?

**My Model**

```html
class Offri extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'viaggio';
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['citta_part','citta_arrivo','user_id'], 'required'],
            [['data_part','ora_part','data_arrivo','ora_arrivo'],'safe'],
            [['posti_disponibili', 'conferma_utenze', 'user_id','posti_max'], 'integer'],
            [['prezzo'], 'number'],
            [['citta_part', 'via_part', 'citta_arrivo', 'via_arrivo', 'veicolo'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['note'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['wifi', 'bagno', 'ac_dc','condizioni'],'integer'],
             [['user_id'], 'unique'],
            [['user_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_id' => 'id']],
           
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id_viaggio' => Yii::t('app', 'Id Viaggio'),
            'citta_part' => Yii::t('app', 'Citta Part'),
            'via_part' => Yii::t('app', 'Via Part'),
            'ora_part' => Yii::t('app', 'Ora Part'),
            'data_part' => Yii::t('app', 'Data Part'),
            'posti_disponibili' => Yii::t('app', 'Posti Disponibili'),
            'conferma_utenze' => Yii::t('app', 'Conferma Utenze'),
            'prezzo' => Yii::t('app', 'Prezzo'),
            'note' => Yii::t('app', 'Note'),
            'citta_arrivo' => Yii::t('app', 'Citta Arrivo'),
            'data_arrivo' => Yii::t('app', 'Data Arrivo'),
            'ora_arrivo' => Yii::t('app', 'Ora Arrivo'),
            'via_arrivo' => Yii::t('app', 'Via Arrivo'),
            'veicolo' => Yii::t('app', 'Veicolo'),
            'posti_max' => Yii::t('app', 'Posti Max'),
            'wifi' => Yii::t('app', 'Wifi'),
            'bagno' => Yii::t('app', 'Bagno'),
            'ac_dc' => Yii::t('app', 'Ac Dc'),
          
        ];
    }
    
  
    public function getUser()
    {
         
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])->inverseOf('offri');
    }
```

the field that I want to save in the table is user_id , which must be to the account id

**My Controller**

```html
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\filters\AccessRule;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;
use app\models\Accounts;
use app\models\Offri;
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                        [
                        'actions' => ['create'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['admin'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['view', 'search'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?', '@', 'admin'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

   
   public function actionregisterUser()
    {
       $model = new Accounts();
    

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($user = $model->registerUser()) {
                if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                    return $this->goHome();
                }
            }
        }

}
public function actionSomeAction($id) {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => (string) $model->_id]);
        }elseif (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            return $this->renderAjax('_form', [
                        'model' => $model
            ]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('_form', [
                        'model' => $model
            ]);
        }
    }
public function actionOffri()
   {
    $model = new Offri;


    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& $model->validate() && $model->save())
       {
   
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Hai inserito i dati correttamente');
    return $this->render('offri', ['model' => $model]);
       }else {
             Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Completa correttamente tutti i campi.');
    return $this->render('offri', ['model' => $model]);
        
   

}
}
}
```

Comment: update your controller code also

Comment: I have update code

Comment: if you want current loged in user id? to save user_id

Comment: yes, I want to save in the table user id , id accout get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your `actionOffri()` like below

```
public function actionOffri()
{
    $model = new Offri;
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){

        $model->user_id=Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            if($model->validate() && $model->save()){
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Hai inserito i dati correttamente');
            return $this->render('offri', ['model' => $model]);
       }else {
             Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Completa correttamente tutti i campi.');
            return $this->render('offri', ['model' => $model]);
      }
}
```

**work my Controller**

```html
public function actionOffri()
   {
    $model = new Offri;

     $model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& $model->validate() && $model->save())
       {
       
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Hai inserito i dati correttamente');

    return $this->render('offri', ['model' => $model]);
       }else {
             Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Completa correttamente tutti i campi.');
    return $this->render('offri', ['model' => $model]);
        
   

}
}
```

**work my model**

```html
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['citta_part','citta_arrivo'], 'required'],
            [['data_part','ora_part','data_arrivo','ora_arrivo'],'safe'],
            [['posti_disponibili', 'conferma_utenze','posti_max'], 'integer'],
            [['prezzo'], 'number'],
            [['citta_part', 'via_part', 'citta_arrivo', 'via_arrivo', 'veicolo'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['note'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['wifi', 'bagno', 'ac_dc','condizioni'],'integer'],
           
           
        ];
    }
```

i have removed in rules 'user_id'

Comment: I think it's a problem of relationship between tables because no relation save the attributes but not user_id . Some other solution ?

Comment: [['citta_part','citta_arrivo'], 'required'], remove ,'user_id' in your model